# React - Formik - No Validate on disabled controls

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am looking for a solution to stop yup validation on controls that are disabled, invisible or not rendered.

I have such a control:

```
<MySelectInput disabled placeholder={mandantOptions[0].text} name="mandant" options={mandantOptions} clearable={false} />


const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    mandant: Yup.number().min(1, 'Select Mandant'),
})
```

Can some please help me to figure out how i can stop validation with yup when the field is disabled or invisible, or not rendered.

Thanks a lot for any help
Arga